# Should I CoTaskMemFree?

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling, managed

I have a code in `C#` which gets some string from a native `dll`:

```
[DllImport(pluginName)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
private static extern string GetStringResource(int key);
```

and `C++`:

```
extern "C"
{
    LPWSTR __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall GetStringResource(int key)
    {
        std::wstring result = GetStringForKey(key);
        wchar_t* buffer = (wchar_t*)::CoTaskMemAlloc((result.size() + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t));
        if (buffer == nullptr)
            return buffer;

        std::copy(result.begin(), result.end(), buffer);
        buffer[result.size()] = L'\0';
        return buffer;
    }
}
```

Now the questions are

- Should I `CoTaskMemFree` the allocated string in `C#`?
- What if I remove `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]` from `C#` function signature? Should I free it then?

Comment: 1. No, the pinvoke marshaller already does that.  2. You can't remove it, but favor CharSet = CharSet.Unicode in the [DllImport] attribute so it isn't necessary.

Comment: @HansPassant How would the marshaller know which of the Free functions (CoTaskMemFree, LocalFree, ...) it has to call?

Comment: It doesn't have to guess, it always uses CoTaskMemFree().

Comment: @HansPassant I did not know this, thanks. It is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-behavior

Comment: Thanks guys. @HansPassant could you please make your comment as an answer?

Comment: Doublecheck: It doesn't matter if I have `CharSet.Unicode` in the `[DlIlmport]` or `MarshalAs` or nothing at all... I never have to free the memory manually, right?